# Where Visual Studio does save DLL references paths?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dependencies

I have looked in the .vbproj and i thought visual studio 2010 was using the HintPath element in the file to figure out where to load the referenced DLL. But it seem that it is wrong. Problem i have is that Nuget program when done getting the facultative DLLs (important, do not apply to non-facultative ones) point to the bin of the actual project instead of pointing to the packages folder. So i decided to write a small application which correct the path to thoses DLL from the .vbproj. The references in my project of an actual project doesn't seem to reflect the vbproj hint path.

So my question is.. Where Visual Studio does save DLL references paths ? and what it do with it.

Comment: Why a downvote on this ? i want to know why visual studio doesn't doesn't to refresh based on hintpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint Path is right place, in addition you can check for Project/Properties/Reference paths in the IDE